# Git-like scheduler program for Linux

Tags: linux, gratis, project-management

I became a user of Git because of the many advantages it has.
Personally I love the structure and organization behind every commit one does.

I would like to know if exist a similar program (something like a scheduler) that can manage
the jobs submited in the linux kernel. I usually have different programs running under the same exec because I only change a couple of parameters in the program, so it's faster just to compile and send the jobs without changing my Makefile or altering more the source code of my program. I know the pids, of course, but sometimes it gets confusing if I submit the jobs with the nohup command.

It would be fantastic a program tha records the PID and also let you add a comment to the job,
instead of doing manually of course.

Comment: If you are looking for a scheduler to perform jobs at a future date or time then you can use a cron. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: I think cron is more related when you want to do repetitive tasks. Here I just want a program that records the PID, the location of the exec, and a brief description that I could give to the running program.